# Having trouble deleting custom styles in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I use a large workbook in Excel 2016 and it appears that a large number of custom styles have been imported into the workbook and are messing with the formatting of cells in the workbook. I've tried using the following code to delete the custom styles

```
Sub clear_all_styles()

Dim styT As Style

For Each styT In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
    If styT.BuiltIn = False Then
        styT.Locked = False
        styT.Delete
    End If
Next styT

End Sub
```

but the styles are still listed in the Styles ribbon when I execute the code. In addition, when I try to manually delete the styles by right-clicking on them, they don't get deleted.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
Sub clear_all_styles()

 Dim styT As Style
 On Error Resume Next
 For Each styT In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
     If Not styT.BuiltIn Then
         If styT.Name <> "1" Then styT.Delete
     End If
 Next styT
```

End Sub

Comment: Why the check if the name is unequal `"1"`? Might there be a "special custom style" with this name?

Answer (score 1):

just go on deleting like this:

```
Sub DeleteStyles()
    For Each sty In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not sty.BuiltIn Then
            sty.Delete
        End If
    Next sty
End Sub
```